# What determines the layer a task is in, in an airflow DAG?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

If we look at an example DAG in Airflow we see (Graph View):

[image]

What determines the positions of tasks `also_run_this` and `this_will_skip`? Notice these 2 tasks don't have any connecting lines prior to themselves, which means they could be placed on the same layer (first vertical set of tasks) as `runme_0`, `runme_1` and `runme_2` (using my obviously incorrect assumptions about the DAG).

Is it their runtime that places them in the same layer as `run_after_loop`?

I am looking at the detailed tasks data for this DAG and I don't see anything that distinguishes `also_run_this` and `this_will_skip` from `runme_0` in terms of position:

Here is `runme_0`:

```
{
    "class_ref": {
        "class_name": "BashOperator",
         "module_path": "airflow.operators.bash"
    },
    "depends_on_past": false,
    "downstream_task_ids": ["run_after_loop"],
    "end_date": null,
    "execution_timeout": null,
    "extra_links": [],
    "owner": "airflow",
    "pool": "default_pool",
    "pool_slots": 1,
    "priority_weight": 1,
    "queue": "default",
    "retries": 0,
    "retry_delay": {
        "__type": "TimeDelta",
        "days": 0,
        "microseconds": 0,
        "seconds": 300
    },
    "retry_exponential_backoff": false,
    "start_date": "2021-06-17T00:00:00+00:00",
    "task_id": "runme_0",
    "template_fields": ["bash_command", "env"],
    "trigger_rule": "all_success",
    "ui_color": "#f0ede4",
    "ui_fgcolor": "#000",
    "wait_for_downstream": false,
    "weight_rule": "downstream"
}
```

And here is `also_run_this`:

```
{
    "class_ref": {
        "class_name": "BashOperator",
        "module_path": "airflow.operators.bash"
    },
    "depends_on_past": false,
    "downstream_task_ids": ["run_this_last"],
    "end_date": null,
    "execution_timeout": null,
    "extra_links": [],
    "owner": "airflow",
    "pool": "default_pool",
    "pool_slots": 1,
    "priority_weight": 1,
    "queue": "default",
    "retries": 0,
    "retry_delay": {
        "__type": "TimeDelta",
        "days": 0,
        "microseconds": 0,
        "seconds": 300
    },
    "retry_exponential_backoff": false,
    "start_date": "2021-06-17T00:00:00+00:00",
    "task_id": "also_run_this",
    "template_fields": ["bash_command", "env"],
    "trigger_rule": "all_success",
    "ui_color": "#f0ede4",
    "ui_fgcolor": "#000",
    "wait_for_downstream": false,
    "weight_rule": "downstream"
}
```

It would make sense if the same layer was based on parallelism (all tasks in the same vertical layer run in parallel) but this would require some thresholding of the run times, and I don't see any such data available in the DAG or TASK information.

In fact, looking at the Tree View, it appears to show `runme_0`, `runme_1`, `runme_2`, `also_run_this` and `this_will_skip` all running at the same time:

[image]

As per @bruno-uy 's comment, it appears the Graph View has a UI "problem." Definitely not very intuitive.

Comment: Do you see any delay in the schedule of those two tasks that you mentioned? I think those should start at the same time and it's just a UI "problem" not showing them at the same level. I didn't see any reference from Airflow that says that it must be at the same level to start at the same time.

Comment: @bruno-uy No, the layer 1 and layer 2 tasks both have the same retry_delay, and there's no other mention of delay in the task instance information. Interesting you suggest a UI problem, as I also suspected this might be the case. If this is the case, Airflow DAG visuals are not that intuitive.

Comment: Definitely not that intuitive. Try upgrading to Airflow 2 which has good UI improvements. I don't blame them since it's very difficult to "draw" DAGs normally.

Comment: This is Airflow 2 (2.1.0). I just posted the Tree View in the question. Note that it appears to show `runme_0`, `runme_1`, `runme_2`, `also_run_this` and `this_will_skip` all running at the same time, suggesting the Graph View is indeed problematic from a UI perspective. I have recreated the visual using a Sankey diagram, which positions the tasks correctly, looks much better, and can be interactively adjusted to position the tasks visually, as needed.

Comment: Indeed. I was checking [this](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/ui.html#graph-view) and figured out you took the image from there. Sankey diagram could help somehow, but I agree it's not that intuitive in Airflow's case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking that `runme_0`, `runme_1`, `runme_2`, `also_run_this` and `this_will_skip` all running at the same time, we can say that this is a UI "problem" that they're not shown in the same "layer". Airflow doesn't have the "layer" concept, so basically they don't assure the tasks starting at the same time are aligned vertically.

Could be a good improvement for Airflow, or just add another diagram as you mentioned Sankey.